# Understanding jQuery Documentation - Function Arguments

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery functions can have argument choices or no arguments.

The jQuery documentation uses `function() { ..some code.. }` in their examples, but usually don't use `eventData`.

What is the distinction between `eventData` & `eventObject` in:

```
.click( [eventData ], handler(eventObject) )
```

when the syntax can also be:

```
.click( handler(eventObject) )
```

Can `handler(eventObject)` be a user created function like `doSomethingHere()`?

Comment: `eventData` is (optional) data that is passed to the handler when the event is bound. To retrieve it, you use `eventObject.data`. `eventData` can be anything you want to pass (and populates `eventObject.data`), while `eventObject` is something specific jQuery calls every event handler with: https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DEMO - http://jsfiddle.net/P7XU8/

Here `[eventData]` are the *optional* parameter(s) you want to send to the handler.

```
$(".selector").click({param1: "MOM", param2: "DAD"}, myFunc);

function myFunc(event){
    alert(event.data.param1);
    alert(event.data.param2);
}
```

Or

http://jsfiddle.net/P7XU8/1/

```
$(".selector").click({
    param1: "MOM",
    param2: "DAD"
}, function (event) {
    alert(event.data.param1);
    alert(event.data.param2);
});
```

Documentataion & example here https://api.jquery.com/event.data/